# Фразеологизмы на автомобильную тематику

Tags: фразеология

Помогите, пожалуйста, собрать фразеологизмы на автомобильную тематику: водитель, машина, части автомобиля, бензин, вождение и пр. Например: заведенный как машина, как зайцу стоп-сигнал, спустить на тормоза, заносить на поворотах, дорожная карта и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

дать сигнал, заправиться, дать газу

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все примеры классные!